# How can I add google play services to Ionic Android Project?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, google-play-services

I am trying to make this plugin work with my ionic app:

https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-background-geolocation-services

This plugin needs Google Play Services installed to work.

I have installed it through android SDK and followed this steps in order to get the library included into my project:

https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Now if I try to build android project I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Cannot evaluate module google-play-services_lib : Configuration with name 'debug' not found.
```

From some research It seems like that this problem is related to project structure and gradle, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Can anybody help me?

I can also evaluate different free background gps plugins to run into my ionic app.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In [Creating an Android Module](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#CreatingAModule), after installing minimum required SDK, you have the following options:

- **Set up a Library Module** so you can create a new one in the same way as you would create a new application module. With Library Module being set up, you can easily change an existing application module to a library module by changing the plugin assignment in the `build.gradle` file to `com.android.library`.
- **Add a dependency on a library module** by declaring all of the shared components that it includes in the module's manifest file. To add the dependency declaration to the build file, edit the build file for the app module (`app/build.gradle`) and add a dependency on the `lib` module.
- **Reference a library module** with these steps:

  1. Make sure that both the module library and the application module that depends on it are in your project. If one of the modules is missing, import it into your project.
  2. In the project view, right-click the dependent module and select **Open > Module Settings.**
  3. Right-click the plus icon to add a new dependencies. If you are adding references to multiple libraries, you can set their relative priority (and merge order) by selecting a library and using the Up and Down controls.
  4. Use the **Scope** drop-down to select how the dependency will be applied.
  5. Click **Apply** to create the dependency and **OK** to close the **Project Structure** window.
- **Declare library components in the manifest file**. You must add declarations of all components that the applications will use that are imported from a library module. For example, you must declare any <`activity`>, <`service`>, <`receiver`>, <`provider`>, and so on, as well as <`permission`>, <`uses-library`>, and similar elements.

Comment: So i have to create an Android Module? IHow can I attach the libary declairing it in manifest file?